# heroku legacy ssl solution broken in chrome 70

Tags: google-chrome, heroku, ssl-certificate

updated to Version 70.0.3538.35 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)

I changed the dns "A" record per heroku's old instructions so that all requests (http , https ) to my site would reroute in Heroku front=end  to my $herokuapp.1234  domain.  it just broke.

and a site no longer renders without the ssl warnings :

In the past , i just let Heroku's front end handle the SSL requests , routing them to my app but as of today , in chrome that does not work anymore..

have [looked here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint) but not sure what to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some months ago I switched everything over the the free certificates provided by Heroku's ACM and haven't looked back - free, automatic, easy - so unless you have a compelling reason to be using the legacy infrastructure I'd suggest make the switch.

As Heroku says (at that link you posted):

New Heroku applications should use Heroku SSL, which includes Automated Certificate Management (ACM). The SSL Endpoint add-on described in this article is only recommended for supporting legacy Heroku applications, or for applications that require custom security policies.